# Let $(X, T_X)$ and $(Y, T_Y)$ be topological spaces with bijective function $h:X \to Y$ continuous and open. Then $h$ is a topological equivalence.

Tags: general-topology

**Problem: Let $(X, T_X)$ and $(Y, T_Y)$ be topological spaces with bijective function $h:X \to Y$ continuous and open. Then $h$ is a topological equivalence between $X$ and $Y$.**

It says that, $h:X \to Y$ is a bijection, therefore it is a 1-1 correspondence and also onto (i.e. it is injective and surjective). So, there is a one-to-one correspondence between $X$ and $Y$ with respect to $h$. Now, we know that, a function is said to be continuous iff for every $V \in T_Y$, $f^{-1}(V) \in T_X$, and it is said to be open iff for every $U \in T_X$, we have $f(U) \in T_Y$. So, $h:X \to Y$ is continuous implies if we let $V$ be an open set of $Y$ so that $V \in T_Y$, then using the property of continuous functions, we can say that its inverse is open in X and therefore $f^{-1}(V) \in T_X$.

A function is called open if it maps an open set to another open set, therefore $h:X \to Y$ is open => if we let any $U \subset X$, $U$ is open in $X$, so $U \in T_X$. So, $h(U)$ is open in $Y$, so $h(U) \in T_Y$.

So, $h:X \to Y$ is 1-1 correspondence, such that $\forall U \in T_X$, $f(U) \in T_Y$, and $\forall V \in T_Y$, we have the pre-image $f^{-1}(V) \in T_X$ which basically proves topological equivalence b/w $X$ and $Y$.

This is how I proved this proposition. Can someone verify this and let me know if this correct or not. Do feel free to give a better notation and style. Appreciate your help and support.

Comment: This looks good. By topological equivalence do you mean homeomorphism?

Comment: Two topological spaces $(X, T_X)$ and $(Y, T_Y)$ are said to be topologically equivalent iff there exists a one-to-one correspondence $f: X \to Y$, such that $\forall U \in T_X$, $f(U) \in T_Y$, and $\forall V \in T_Y$, $f^{-1}(V) \in T_X$. This is the definition which my prof gave us and I am supposed to use this to prove the proposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is almost no proof. By assumption $h$ is already a bijection.

$h$ is open is saying the same as $$\forall U \in \mathcal{T}_X: h[U] \in \mathcal{T}_Y$$

and $h$ is continuous says

$$\forall V \in \mathcal{T}_Y: h^{-1}[V] \in \mathcal{T}_X$$

so practically **by your definition** an open continuous function fulfills the essential demands on being an equivalence. We need a bijection for an equivalence but that is part of your assumption too (the previous facts hold for all $h$, bijective or not).

Comment: so true, u just use the definitions and thats it, ur done. :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "topological equivalence" ? That $h$ is a homeomorphism ? Then it's straightforward by the fact that $h$ is open. Given your hypothesis, the only think you have to prove is that $h^{-1}$ is continuous. But their is more or less nothing to prove since this arise from the fact that $h$ is open.

Comment: Two topological spaces $(X, T_X)$ and $(Y, T_Y)$ are said to be topologically equivalent iff there exists a 1-1 correspondence $f: X \to Y$, such that $\forall U \in T_X$, $f(U) \in T_Y$, and $\forall V \in T_Y$, $f^{-1}(V) \in T_X$. This is the definition which my prof gave us and I am supposed to use this to prove the proposition.

Comment: how do I show/prove that $h$ is open? and also where its open?

Comment: It's in the hypothesis. (look at your title).

Comment: ok got it. cool thanks!!

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is good. Everything can be compactly written as: if $h:X\to Y$ is a function with the inverse $f:Y\to X$ then for any subset $U\subseteq X$ we have $h(U)=f^{-1}(U)$. And so $h$ is open if and only if $f$ is continuous and vice versa.

Comment: ok got it, so I also need to show that the inverse of $h$, i.e. $f: Y \to X$ is continuous, right?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun well, it seems to depend on what your definition of "topological equivalence" (a.k.a. homeomorphism) is. Typically $f$ is a homeomorphism if and only if it is a continuous bijection with a continuous inverse. And as I said in my post, this is easily seen to be equivalent to the fact that $f$ is a continuous and open bijection.